# How can I restart the watcher when it was failed?

Tags: rust

everyone
I am using rust to code a program to notify a directory

1.Start a watcher
2.loop hit the case and then do sth.

because i use the Ok(DebouncedEvent::Create(p)), so i first remove the directory(is being watched),and then creat it, but the watcher fails to keeping watching

so i think fs maybe be not atomicity, so i sleep 3s, but it fails again

and then i try to delete the files but not the directory but it fails again

start a watcher

```rust
    // Create a channel to receive the events.
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    // Create a watcher
    let mut watcher: RecommendedWatcher = try!(Watcher::new(tx.clone(), Duration::from_secs(policy_interval as u64)));
    // Path to be monitored
    try!(watcher.watch(metrics_repo_path.as_path(), RecursiveMode::Recursive));
```

my loop

```rust
            loop
            { // Step 2: Start monitoring metrics repository
                match rx.recv()
                {
                    Ok(DebouncedEvent::Create(p)) =>
                    {
                        eprintln!("OK OK, loop start");
                        if let Some(ext) = p.extension()
                        {
                                if num_log_files == num_instances
                                { // We have all logs for this epoch
 

                                        remove_dir_contents(metrics_repo_path.to_str()).unwrap();
                                        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3000));
                                        // // Remove old rates files
                                        // // TODO: remove only files in the repo
                                        // let _ = Command::new("rm")
                                        //             .arg("-r")
                                        //             .arg(metrics_repo_path.to_str().unwrap())
                                        //             .output()
                                        //             .expect("Failed to remove log files.");
                                        // // Create a new rates folder
                                        // let _ = Command::new("mkdir")
                                        //             .arg(metrics_repo_path.to_str().unwrap())
                                        //             .output()
                                        //             .expect("Failed to create new rates folder.");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    { // No re-configuration was issued
                                        epochs_since_reconfiguration += 1;
                                    }
                                    // Clear epoch information
                                    epoch_files.remove(epoch);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Err(e) => panic!("Monitoring error: {:?}", e),
                    _ => {}
                }
            }
```

the fn

```rust
fn remove_dir_contents<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> io::Result<()> {
    for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        fs::remove_file(entry?.path())?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

i also try just restart the watcher but fails
like this

```rust
    remove_dir_contents(metrics_repo_path.to_str()).unwrap();
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3000));
    try!(watcher.watch(metrics_repo_path.as_path(), RecursiveMode::Recursive));
```

**In my opinoin my code will go to the condition**

```rust
Ok(DebouncedEvent::Create(p))
```

**but it fails go to it even though new file was created in the watched file **
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mention that various things "fail" but don't describe what that means. Does your program panic or return an error? If so, what is the error? If not, what is it not doing that you think it should be doing?

Comment: Incidentally, `try!` is deprecated, just use `?` instead.

Comment: Thanks cdhowie and BlackBeans, first fail means my code couldn't go to the condition Ok(DebouncedEvent::Create(p)) even though the file was created under the directory watched, and try! is the code is a rust program for OSDI'18 and i am a beginner for learning rust, I will use ? thanks